# When I install twisted, it missed out some files

Tags: python, pip, twisted

I installed twisted with pip, but it missed some of the files (_win32stdio.py and _pollingfile.py).

I tried copying those files into the directory(site-packages) and it work well.

But I don't know why pip missed those files.

---

English is my second language, Please forgive my grammar mistakes.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You copy what into which directory? You "don't why" what?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall twisted and reinstall it. If the error still persists, check you installed Python from [python.org](http://www.python.org)  and try re-installing python as a whole. Try installing from terminal as well.